# Writing to JSON - Converting \u00a3 to £

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, utf-8

I am using Selenium and python to scrape a website. I am scraping some '£' Characters, however I am getting this instead: `\u00a3`, when writing to JSON (they appear as '£' with I print them to terminal).

I understand they are Unicode and I need them in UTF8 (?). I've tried a few things I've found on SO and haven't had much success.

I have tried .replace (.replace('\u00a3', '£') - However I'm not having much success.

How do I get the characters to look like '£' instead of `\u00a3`?

This is the line that's printing incorrectly. Let me know if you want to see my entire code.

```
price = page.find_element_by_class_name('header_tags').text
```

Comment: You might want to look at encoding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `json.dump()` or `json.dumps()`, try setting `ensure_ascii=False`

Answer (score 6):

you can encode the string like below

```
s = 'This is a Pound sign \u00a3'
s.encode('utf8')
print(s)
```

**Output**

`This is a Pound sign £`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `text("utf-8")` while printing as follows:

```
print(page.find_element_by_class_name('header_tags').text("utf-8"))
```

But this issue can occur at some lines as well. So as per best practices start the *Python* file with the line:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

An example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# other lines of code
price = page.find_element_by_class_name('header_tags').text
```